# probability of integer dot product being zero

Tags: statistics

How is the $L^2$ norm of the solution from an integer relation algorithm (read: PSLQ) distributed for integer inputs?  Common factors among the inputs to PSLQ may have to be taken into consideration.

Put another way, I have a fixed integer vector $u$ to be dotted with an integer vector $v$ with $0<|v|<C$.  What is the probability of such a $v$ existing for which $<u,v>=0$?

I ran some Monte Carlos, and compared actual results from PSLQ to a model assuming dot products are normally distributed, using an observed variance.  In almost every case the solution from PSLQ was estimated to be smaller than 100% of random solutions, or larger than 100% of random solutions.  Very frustrating but even more intriguing than frustrating!